# Is the context manager only for raising exceptions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it good or bad practice to use context manager in python only for validating some data and handling exceptions to make code cleaner?

This is what I mean:

```
@contextmanager
def validate_data(a, b):
  if a != b:
    raise ValidationError("Wrong values")
  if a ==- 1:
    raise ValidationError("You can't use -1")
  if a ==- 2:
    raise ValidationError("You can't use -2")
  # etc validations
  yield

if __name__ == '__main__':
  a = 1
  b = 2
  with validate_data(a, b):
    print(a + b)
```

The problem is almost all information what I found about context managers in Python is about handling connections or reading files operations.

Can I use context managers to simple operations like this one?

As for me it looks like a good example of separating responsibilities, validation is separated from function body and you can concentrate on what function does, not reading all those lines of validation.

Comment: I fail to see the point of using a context manager in the situation shown rather than just using a normal function.

Comment: @jwodder true, I have already fixed yield. b - this is very simplified example. lets assume I have a normal function, which can have 10 `if` conditions which can raise any exceptions - so I want to move those 10 ifs to context manager. Just to make function code cleaner.

Comment: Why not just make `validate_data` a normal function and do `b = 2; validate_data(a, b); print(a + b)`? I don't see that all the extra is giving you anything.

Comment: @JETM because usual workflow where I want use this - in django views, where I want to raise an error explicitly, what I can't do with usual function.

Comment: slightly confused, why can't a normal function raise the error explicitly?  @Chiefir

Comment: Even the [official Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) on that decorator shows an example of managing a resource, the usual use case. I've never seen someone do what you're doing here, and I don't understand where you got that code from.

Comment: @Paritosh Singh ok, seems my example is too simplified. The case when I want to use this - is a django view, where I want make some validations and raise some `http` errors. Raising those errors is not possible outside the scope of the view, so I can't delegate that functionality to separate function. So I want use context manager here - to make a view cleaner and still it can raise responses with different `http status codes`.

Comment: @Silvio Mayolo read a comment above please

Comment: I worry you don't understand how exceptions work. If you call a function and that function raises an exception, then you, as the caller, can still catch the exception. Exceptions dynamically unwind the call stack, so you can still contain it without context managers.

Comment: @Silvio Mayolo django exception is not a real exception - it is a http response with specified status code. See my edit, or make an answer how this can be done with your approach?

Comment: If you use `raise` with it, then it's a "real" exception. And you can't `raise` integers like you do in your edited code. So unfortunately I'm more confused now than I was before.

Comment: @Silvio Mayolo have you written in Django? I have mentioned that this is a pseudocode. You can read that integer something like `MyCustomExceptionWhichReturns404` for example, where integer is a http status code.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, a function that simply returns `True` (for valid data) or `False` (for invalid data) and an `if` statement would be clearer.

```
def is_valid_data(a, b):
    if a != b:
        return False
    ...
    return True

if is_valid_data(a, b):
    print(a + b)
```

Context managers are primarily useful for ensuring that something gets run *after* the body of the `with` statement, whether or not any exceptions are raised during the execution of that body. It was intended as a simpler replacement for a pattern like

```
# 1) Initialize some stuff
try:
    # 2) Do something with the stuff
finally:
    # 3) Do stuff whether or not the above
```

A context manager encapsulates steps 1 and 3:

```
with context_manager as cm:
    # Do something
```

The `with` statement ensures that `cm.__enter__` is run before the body, and ensures that `cm.__exit__` is run, even if an exception would prevent the entire body of the `with` statement (or anything after it) from running.

Comment: This does not solve a problem when I want to raise different errors on different conditions.

Comment: Then raise them. The only thing the `with` statement does is catch the first exception and passes it to the `__exit__` method of the context manager, which may or may not re-raise it. It does not itself *handle* the exception.

Comment: As I said I want use it in django views, raising errors with custom http response codes - and raising those errors elsewhere except view has no effect, so contextmanager helps to keep views clean (in some very few cases). I know how context managers work and by now have read all available documentation about them. But still don&#39;t know what is wrong with my approach. If it is possible - why not to use it? Some time ago coroutines also apeared as side effect of generators.